# ¿Como pasar a la vista blade de Laravel el dato correcto de una colección?

Tags: laravel-blade

tengo un problema que no se resolver. Debo mostrar cuantos elementos con status 1 tiene cada formulario principal en la vista y tal cual lo tengo solo me devuelve el primer elemento que es 0 para todas las iteraciones.

En la vista:

```
  `@foreach ($forms as $form)
     <td>
          {{$form->id}}
          <p class="red_ball">{{$count_actions}}</p>
     </td>
  @endforeach`
```

En el controlador:

```
        foreach($forms as $form){
        $forms_actions = FormAction::where('form_id', '=', $form->id)
            ->where('status', '=', 1)->get();

        $count_actions = count($forms_actions);

    }

    return view('forms.index',compact('forms', 'count_actions'));
```

Gracias de antemano!!

Comment: yo veo el uso de `count`, para que lo usas?, es decir vas a devolver una colección o solo vas a devolver el conteo?, otra duda: ¿por qué iteras con un `foreach` en tu controlador?

Comment: Hola, pues lo cierto es que estoy aprendiendo y pensé que debía ponerlo así. Ya ves que no me sale... me puedes ayudar? Si me enseñas a hacerlo mejor, te lo agradezco mucho ;)

Comment: Solo vas a mostrar el total o también el id?

Comment: El id también lo muestro, y ese sale bien. Solo que ahora debo añadir este nuevo dato del status que comenté en la pregunta.

Comment: El count me dice cuantos elementos con status 1 tiene cada id.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que deseas es mandar a la vista el conteo de: *los elementos con status 1*, entonces has esto:

```
$forms_actions = FormAction::where('form_id', '=', $form->id)
                           ->where('status', '=', 1)
                           ->count();
```

Con lo anterior mandas a la vista el conteo de este modo:

```
return view('forms.index',compact('forms_actions '));
```

Para imprimirlo en la vista así:

```
{{ $forms_actions }}
```

Ahora si también deseas mandar el `id` yo solo agregaría al `compact` la propiedad `$form` así:

```
return view('forms.index',compact('forms_actions ', 'form'));
```

Imprimiendo ambas sería así:

```
{{ $forms_actions }}
{{ $form->id }}
```

**Referencias**

- [`count` Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-count)

Comment: De esta forma lo empecé y me sigue dando el mismo resultado '0'... El id si es el correcto, pero el status no.

Answer (score 0):

ya lo resolví. No se porque no estaba reconociendo   la variable del atributo. Le puse otra que utilizo en el proyecto y ahí funcionó.

Comment: Tienes dos perfiles?

Comment: Por favor, añade más información a la respuesta: ¿cuáles fueron los cambios que realizaste? ¿qué variable de atributo no se reconocía y cuál sí? Lee [answer] y completa el [tour] para más información.

Comment: Cristina tenes dos perfiles? necesitas unirlos? perdiste acceso? deja un comentario con mi nombre (@gbianchi) y trato de ayudarte. Y por otro lado, lee los links que te paso alvaro, y tambien tene en cuenta que si ese es tu error, tu pregunta es directamente no reproducible.